# React navigation state management without redux

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm using [React Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org) library for my React Native project and struggling to understand how to handle state with it.
In normal React Native application I can have state at the top level component and pop events from child components via props, however with React Navigation it seems that I cannot pass any props to components used as Screens.

After reading through [related GitHub issue](https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/issues/935#issuecomment-294308634) it seems that library devs are very opinionated in forcing everyone to use some kind of global event handler - redux or mobx, I guess.

[The handler](https://github.com/Maxim-Filimonov/plural_todo/blob/494ab9816bf43ce384d34ee10eeddbf1a8bc9d7d/TaskForm.js#L67) which needs to modify the following [state](https://github.com/Maxim-Filimonov/plural_todo/blob/494ab9816bf43ce384d34ee10eeddbf1a8bc9d7d/Home.js#L7). I got stuck when I started to try to move the state inside the app as I couldn't figure out how to:

1. Pass the handler to the TaskForm component.
2. Pass the state as props to TaskList if its rendered as part of App.js

Please, avoid replying "just use redux". I believe that using redux in this example would be massive overkill.

Comment: in your code `Home` and `TaskForm` are sibilings. if you want one to modify the state in the other you need to have that state shared by a common ancestor, which in your case is `PluralTodo`. Presumably you can call the `StackNavigator` function inside PluralTodo's render method to initialize your nav and pass any handlers / state there

Comment: That’s exactly is the problem. I’m not sure how to pass handlers and state there

Comment: like this? `Main: {screen: props => <MainScreen yourProps={..} {...props} />}`,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After being inspired by steffeydev I looked more around react community issues and found a very simple example of wrapper using function.

It's surprisingly [simple solution](https://github.com/Maxim-Filimonov/plural_todo/blob/6f2810f1b03c8062619b88989818836cc3f2736e/App.js#L7) and I don't know why I didn't think about it before.
The function is the following:

`const createComponent = (instance, props) =>
  navProps => React.createElement(instance, Object.assign({}, props, navProps));`

Thanks for inspiration and pointing me to screenProps which lead me to finding this solution.

Answer (score 3):

I use react native and react navigation in my app without redux, and so far it’s working great. The trick is passing `screenProps` all the way down the line.

For example, I have a More view. I create a basic More view with 2 sub views in a stack:

```
class More extends Component {
    render() {
        return <something>
    }
}

class SubView1 extends Component {...}
class SubView2 extends Component {...}
```

Then I create the stack:

```
const MoreStack = StackNavigator({
More: {
    screen: More
}, 
SubView1: {
    screen: SubView1,
},
...
}, options);
```

And then I create a wrapper class that I export:

```
export default class MoreExport extends Component {
    static navigationOptions = {
        title: "More"
    }

    render() {
        return <MoreStack screenProps={this.props.screenProps} />;
    }
}
```

If all of this is in More.js, I can just import More from More.js and use it anywhere else.

If I then pass in screenProps to my root view and then have a wrapper class for each layer, I can pass the screenProps all the way down, and all views can access them using `this.props.screenProps`.

I use a wrapper like the one above around each StackNavigator and TabNavigator, and the screenProps are passed all the way down.

For example, in my root class’s render method, I could do:

```
return <More screenProps={{prop1: something, prop2: somethingElse}} />
```

And then the More class and each SubView in the MoreStack would all have access to these props.

Feel free to let me know if you want more clarification!

Disclaimer: I don’t know if this is the correct or recommended way to do it, but it does work

Comment: When I converted my app to react-navigation, I basically just made these wrappers and replaced instances of this.props with this.props.screenProps, and most of the logic still worked.

Comment: Can you show an example of what would be inside More render? I don't understand what do you render inside to make it switch between different subviews. Converting my views to using your wrappers now

Comment: What is inside More render is whatever you want, I have a few buttons that call this.props.navigation.navigate(“SubView1”),  and the StackNavigator handles the pop onto the stack

Comment: Keep in mind that More is technically a sibling of SubView1, and MoreStack is the common parent.  Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1):

You can set param to navigation like this:

```
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
    return {
        tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor, focused }) =>
            <View>
                <Icon name="bell-ring" size={24} color={focused ? 'green' : 'black'} />
                {(navigation.state.params.badgeCount && navigation.state.params.badgeCount > 0) ?
                    <Text>{navigation.state.params.badgeCount}</Text>
                    :
                    <View></View>
                }
            </View>
    }
}
```

and change badgeCount by:

```
this.props.navigation.setParams({ badgeCount: 3 })
```

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with the same issue and tried some of the other answers before discovering the following part of the documentation for React Navigation: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-navigator.html#params.

Essentially, each `Screen` in the `Stack` can be passed `params` which can include handlers and then the various screens can interact with the application state.

My general structure is then to have an `App` class with state and handlers and the handlers are then passed into each Navigation `Screen` as needed. I'm not sure if I have this pattern right, but it's the way I understood the general React tutorial.

Example: In my demo app, I have a page flow like this:

- Park finder screen -> Park detail screen (with `Bookmark` action)
- Bookmark list screen -> Park detail screen

If you find a park, you can click on a `Bookmark` button which adds the park to the list of bookmarks shown on the Bookmark screen. You can then click on a park bookmark to see the details.

My `App` looks generally like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

// Screens
import ParkFinderScreen from './Components/ParkFinderScreen';
import ParkBookmarksScreen from './Components/ParkBookmarksScreen';
import ParkDetailsScreen from './Components/ParkDetailsScreen';

// Navigation
import { createStackNavigator, createBottomTabNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      bookmarks: new Map()
    };
  }

  // Bookmark the park shown in the detail section.
  handleBookmark (park) {
    let newBookmarks = this.state.bookmarks;

    newBookmarks.set(park.parkCode, park);

    this.setState({
      bookmarks: newBookmarks
    });
  }

  render() {
    const FinderStack = createStackNavigator(
      {
        ParkFinder: {
          screen: ParkFinderScreen
        },
        ParkFinderDetails: {
          screen: ParkDetailsScreen,
          params: {
            handleBookmark: (park) => this.handleBookmark(park),
          }
        },
      }
    );

    const BookmarksStack = createStackNavigator(
      {
        ParkBookmarks: {
          screen: ParkBookmarksScreen,
          params: {
            bookmarks: this.state.bookmarks
          }
        },
        ParkBookmarksDetails: {
          screen: ParkDetailsScreen,
        },
      }
    );

    const AppNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator(
      {
        Bookmarks: BookmarksStack,
        Finder: FinderStack,
      }
    );

    const AppContainer = createAppContainer(AppNavigator);

    return (
      <AppContainer/>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

I'm using Apollo Client, but I've removed those parts.

In the `Screen` components, you can access the `props` like other ones using `this.props.navigation.getParam('bookmarks')`.

One issue I encountered was that whenever I change the App state, I'm taken to the first screen. The state is updated, but it's a little disorienting. I'm not sure if there is a way to update the App state while staying on the screen. I can sort of understand that given the App state has updated, all the children need to be updated and so the current screen (which is part of a child I think) is reset. I don't know if that is a limitation of the system or a byproduct of how I designed the components.

I hope this helps someone. This seems to keep with the intended behavior of React Native. The library team really seems to want you to not use Redux. https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/redux-integration.html